# PSU Modification

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I have a salvaged hp printer psu with 31v output which is not that useful, upon inspection I found it has uc3842 ic, My guess is that it regulates output voltage using that pc817 optocoupler and a 7.5k smd resistor (connected to pin2 of uc3842).

How can I modify it to have 12v or 24v output, my guess is i will have to change the 7.5k resistor but is there a general formula to calculate the resistor? Can I use a variable resistor to have a variable output?

Also, does reducing output voltage means I can modify current sense resistor to get slightly more amps at output? It is rated for 1.29A max

[image: Backside]

[Source](https://m.imgur.com/gallery/sHr09Ig)

[image: Mainboard]

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8N2Z.jpg)

Comment: Yes but the powertrain (transformer, switching devices, capacitors, output inductors) was designed for 31V output. Dramatically changing the output voltage in such a manner is going to potentially change a lot of the operating points and could result in some parts seeing stresses for which they were not designed. Not a good idea in my opinion - just get yourself a 12V supply and be done with it.

Comment: And no, reducing the output voltage does not necessarily mean you can get more current **from an existing circuit**. There may be several components that will be destroyed if you increase the current.

Comment: It is very likely the UC3842 is self-supplied via an auxiliary winding delivering 12-16 V probably. If you reduce the output voltage by 2.6, then auxiliary voltage will drop to less than 5 V and the part will enter hiccup mode (tic-tic-tic) attempting to resume operations without enough auxiliary supply.

Comment: You might get best results by adding a buck regulator to it. 31v to 12v and the current can be increased by about double.